# Debug.Print not printing the correct value of a variable

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I have a macro that moves some data around in different spreadsheets and I have been trying to figure out why my `Debug.Print` is not printing the long data. It prints the string but wont print the long.

The below code does not produce an error message and the data is moved as I would expect it to be however when I try to use a print statement to print to the Immediate window all I get is the string portion of the print.

I have tried to convert to string using `CStr()` on my long just in case it was a problem with concatenating non-string with string with no change in results. I have tried just printing the long by itself and all it prints is an empty line to the Immediate window.

My question is this:

Is there a reason for my code to not print the long?

I know the results of my MACRO do exactly what I need them to do by manually verify each step with breakpoints but why is Debug.Print not printing the long?

Example results from Debug.Print

```
Last Row for G90_CTR_WS: 
Last Row for L90_CTR_WS: 
Last Row for BU_WB: 
Last Row for rng1: 
Last Row for rng2:
```

Code:

```
On Error GoTo 0
lr_counter = inv_wb.Worksheets(7).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = inv_wb.Worksheets(7).Range("A2:G" & lr_counter)
Debug.Print ("Last Row for G90_CTR_WS: " & lr__counter)

lr_counter = inv_wb.Worksheets(6).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
rng1.Cut Destination:=inv_wb.Worksheets(6).Range("A" & lr_counter + 1)
Debug.Print ("Last Row for L90_CTR_WS: " & lr__counter)

check_for_file = Dir(workbook_directory & "\*backup*")
Set bu_wb = Workbooks.Open(workbook_directory & "\" & check_for_file)

lr_counter = bu_wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = bu_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B" & lr_counter)
Debug.Print ("Last Row for BU_WB: " & lr__counter)

bu_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

lr_counter = inv_wb.Worksheets(6).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = inv_wb.Worksheets(6).Range("A2:A" & lr_counter)
Debug.Print ("Last Row for rng1: " & lr__counter)

check_for_file = Dir(workbook_directory & "\*vehicle*list*")
Set vl_wb = Workbooks.Open(workbook_directory & "\" & check_for_file)
lr_counter = vl_wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng3 = vl_wb.Worksheets(1).Range("I2:I" & lr_counter)
Debug.Print ("Last Row for rng2: " & lr__counter)
```

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module. Then remove the extra underscore from `lr__counter` everywhere you find it.

Comment: You did notice that you have two underscores in the `lr__counter` variable name in the `Debug.Print()` call, right?

Comment: While we're at it, try to avoid using underscores. They are used for implementing Interfaces and may cause issues further down the line

Comment: @L8n The underscores are a habit from PEP8. I started out my first language with Python.

Comment: @MarekFekete That was it. Not sure how I managed two underscores but that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `Option Explicit` and see where the code explodes. - [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)

A way to have automatically written `Option Explicit` is to select "Require Variable Declaration" in the *VBEditor>Tools>Options*:

[image]

In general, I guess it is here:

```
lr_counter = inv_wb.Worksheets(7).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = inv_wb.Worksheets(7).Range("A2:G" & lr_counter)
Debug.Print ("Last Row for G90_CTR_WS: " & lr__counter)
```

`lr__counter` is with 2 `_` and is declared with 1.

Comment: I was trying to use `On Error GoTo 0` but it was not doing anything. Turns out it was the double underscore... Got to love spending hours on a typo...

Comment: @Mike-SMT - put `Option Explicit` on the top of the module, then it would point the typo once you run it.

Comment: That Is good to know I will probably use `Option Explicit` from now on while developing.

Comment: @Mike-SMT - almost everyone uses it. It is actually a built-in feature in the VBEditor, see the screenshot.

Comment: @Thanks for the option to add `Option Explicit` by default but I would rather hard code it so I get in the habit of using it and knowing when to use it.